# Rails - How to delete a belongs_to object when the parent sets the association to nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Contract Model that has a belongs_to to a Timeline. The Timeline is optional, only makes sense for that specific Contract, and the value can be created and then deleted later on, so when the contract.timeline is set to nil, I need to delete the Timeline. Currently, contract.timeline can be set to nil via a contract.update(params) in the controller, so I'm getting orphan Timeline records. What is the best way to delete the Timeline when the parent nils out the association to that object?

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in :dependent that you can pass to a belongs_to call. The code would look something like:

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :timeline, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: I was assuming that option only applies when you delete the parent. Does setting timeline to nil also cause the record to get deleted?

Comment: It will work also when the dependent: :delete. But on both cases the other Contracts will be orphaned...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a before_filter to manually delete the timeline you no longer need.